# How to create a queue at runtime?

Tags: c#, queue

I am writing an application in C#. In this application I am getting data from different ports. Here I want to create a queue with the name equal to the portnumber whenever a new port starts sending data. Can I create such a queue?

Comment: And how would you find (use) those ports from the rest of your code?

Comment: In that queue i want to add the data getting from that port for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to create a queue of received data for each port that is being used, you'd be best having a keyed collection of queues. These queues would be keyed by the port number. So perhaps use a `Dictionary<int, Queue<Data>>`. Then when a request comes in, you can check to see if the port already has a queue; if so, add to that queue; if not, create the queue. i.e.

```
private Dictionary<int, Queue<Data>> mPortQueues = new Dictionary<int, Queue<Data>>();

public void ReceiveData(int portNumber, Data data)
{
    Queue<Data> queue;

    // See if we have a queue
    if (!mPortQueues.TryGetValue(portNumber, out queue))
    {
        // No queue for this port, so create and cache
        queue = new Queue<Data>();

        mPortQueues.Add(portNumber, queue);
    }

    // Queue the data
    queue.Enqueue(data);
}
```

Comment: Here i can create the queue and add it to dictionary along with the port number.But if i want to add the data in the queue of respective port number in another process then how i have to do?Means i written another method in which i am writing the data to respective queue.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your intending, but if your wanting to share the received data between two places (two programs, for instance), then you might be best off setting up a shared service that handles this queue system; where both programs can request the queue information.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest creating a `Dictionary<int, Queue>` and using port number as index.

Comment: i want to add data in queue from one side and using from other side.Is it possible if i use the dictionary?

Comment: You use the dictionary just to access the queue. Then you can add data from one side of the queue and load from the other side.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Queue<KeyValuePair<int, object>>`

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what they want as their access is by port # not by order